# Не могу понять почему не работает align-items: flex-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

````
    display: flex;
}

.first_block{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px; 
}

.second_block{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px; 

}

.mini_block{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.third_block{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px; 

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает, но у вас `flex-direction: column` поэтому вам наверное нужно `justify-items: flex-end`

Comment: Cпасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!